# How to stop didBeginContact called repeatedly SceneKit

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, game-physics

I have two kinematic object. One kinematic object moves constantly towards the other due to a SCNAction. The other kinematic object stays put. When the two collide, the "didBegin contact" gets called non-stop. I don't know why this is. Is it because of the SCNAction? How can I fix this? Or does anyone know why this is happening?

heres the setup code

```js
var ballNode : SCNNode!
var referenceNode : SCNReferenceNode!

func setUpNodes(){
        ballNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ball", recursively: true)
        ballNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ledge", ofType: "scn", inDirectory: "art.scnassets") else { return }
        let referenceURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        referenceNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: referenceURL)
        referenceNode!.load()
        referenceNode!.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -20)
        referenceNode?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
        referenceNode?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 4
        referenceNode?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 4
        referenceNode?.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(referenceNode!)
        referenceNode!.runAction(SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 30), duration: 6))
    }
```

heres the didbegin contact code.

```js
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
        let nodeA = contact.nodeA
        let nodeB = contact.nodeB
        if(nodeA.name == "ball" && nodeB.name == "ledge2"){
            print("contact")   
        }
    }
```

heres the console after running the code.

> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact
> contact...

Comment: You should post some of your code and setup procedure.

Comment: I added it, can you look over it?

Answer (score 0):

This might be dated, but you need to test both ways and as long as it is in "contact", then you'll get the response you got.  I have not tried them, but you have didUpdate, and DidEnd as options.

You said you didn't want it to happen non-stop, but that's the way it works, so possibly a property that says the node is "In contact" and then skip the detection for that node.

```
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact)
    {
        if(data.gameState == .run)
        {
            guard let nodeNameA = contact.nodeA.name else { return }
            guard let nodeNameB = contact.nodeB.name else { return }
            
            if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Explo" && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Missi")
            {
                gameControl.enemyMissileHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameB.suffix(4))!)
            }
            if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Missi" && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Explo")
            {
                gameControl.enemyMissileHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameA.suffix(4))!)
            }
            if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Explo" && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Hive ")
            {
                gameControl.enemyHiveHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameB.suffix(4))!)
            }
            if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Hive " && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Explo")
            {
                gameControl.enemyHiveHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameA.suffix(4))!)
            }
        }
    }
```